# Is there a table level collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, collation

In SQL server, you can set a default collation at the server and database level.  You can also set a collation for a specific field but I couldn't find any reliable documentation about a default collation at the table level.

I always assumed there was no such thing until I took a look at the extended properties of a table in SSMS:

[image: TableExtendedProperties]

Is the `Collation` value referring to the default database (or server) collation or is there's a way to set a default collation for a table that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as a table-level collation. This is the query Management Studio executes to get this data when you select the "Extended Properties" page for the first time:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
dtb.collation_name AS [Collation],
dtb.name AS [DatabaseName2]
FROM
master.sys.databases AS dtb
WHERE
(dtb.name=@_msparam_0)',N'@_msparam_0 nvarchar(4000)',@_msparam_0=N'...'
```

This is simply the database collation. Exactly why it chooses to present this on the table level as well is unclear; probably someone got lazy reusing dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

The next largest level of granularity after *Database* is *Column*

> Collations can be specified at the server, database, column, expression, and identifier levels [[?]](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177439(v=sql.105).aspx).

You cannot specify it at the table level.

([The GUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SQL12.SWB.COMMON.EXTENDEDPROPERTIES.F1)&rd=true) is showing you the *Database* collation either as set at that level or as inherited from the servers collation.)